# Remove rows with repeated index in multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index

I have the following dataframe with a double index. How could I delete those rows where the first index is equal to the second index?

```
First_index             Second_index          Column                          

PitchAngle              RotorSpeed         -0.163742
GenSpeed                PitchAngle         -0.163689
GearboxBearingTemp      PitchAngle         -0.063614                                              
GenSpeed                GenSpeed            0.325689
AmbientTemperature      AmbientTemperature  0.569469
WindDirection           WindDirection      -0.152658
```

Comment: Do you really mean remove the row or do you mean adapt the multi-index where first index is equal to second?

Comment: I mean removing the row, so I'm only interesed in getting those rows where first and second index are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

Load modules

```
import io
import pandas as pd
```

Create the data

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
First_index             Second_index          Column                          
PitchAngle              RotorSpeed         -0.163742
GenSpeed                PitchAngle         -0.163689
GearboxBearingTemp      PitchAngle         -0.063614                                              
GenSpeed                GenSpeed            0.325689
AmbientTemperature      AmbientTemperature  0.569469
WindDirection           WindDirection      -0.152658
"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
```

Do not select the rows where first index is equal to second index

```
df[~(df.First_index == df.Second_index)]
```